# "No terminal library found error" during vim configure

Tags: vim, aix

I tried to build Vim 7.4 in IBM AIX 6.1. When I run the configure script `./configure`  I am getting the following error

```
checking --with-tlib argument... empty: automatic terminal library selection
checking for tgetent in -ltinfo... no
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermlib... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no
checking for tgetent in -lcurses... no
no terminal library found
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

Inspecting the `config.info` I was able to see the following error

```
| int
| main ()
| {
| char s[10000]; int res = tgetent(s, "thisterminaldoesnotexist");
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:10492: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
```

But the curses library (libcurses.a) is present in /usr/lib directory. Then I tried the following command `./configure --with-tlib=curses` and this time getting a different error as below

```
checking --with-tlib argument... curses
checking for linking with curses library... configure: error: FAILED
```

`config.info` error message was

```
| #include <sys/types.h>
| #if STDC_HEADERS
| # include <stdlib.h>
| # include <stddef.h>
| #endif
| #include <signal.h>
| #include "confdefs.h"
|
| int
| main ()
| {
| stack_t sigstk; sigstk.ss_base = 0;
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:10339: result: no
configure:10345: checking --with-tlib argument
configure:10354: result: curses
configure:10357: checking for linking with curses library
configure:10370: gcc -o conftest -g -O2   conftest.c  -lcurses >&5
collect2: /lib/libcurses.a: not a COFF file
configure:10370: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I do the build?

Comment: Better place for this query is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vim_dev

Comment: tgetent do exist in /usr/lib/libcurses.a ... you should check file `config.log` to see the actual error message and the failed testprogram

Comment: Note: It would be cool if `configure` honored option `--with-x=no` or `--without-x`

Comment: OP can examine `config.log` and see the actual error (only the summary is shown in the question).

Comment: regarding `--without-x`: use `sed` to hack file src/auto/configure: `sed_repl 's/$with_x/no/g' src/auto/configure`

Comment: `/lib` should be a symlink to `/usr/lib`; `/usr/lib/libcurses.a` should be a symlink to `/usr/ccs/lib/libxcurses.a`, and `/usr/ccs/lib/libxcurses.a` should be an `ar achive (big format)` (utility file(1) says so)

Comment: how can I solve this?

Comment: There is some problem with your libcurses.a or with your gcc, but no-one except yourself can track it down. Or ask your sys-admin for help.

Comment: Personally, I would try to download and build ncurses rather than figure out how to link to the native curses library. Alternatively, maybe you can download ncurses from this page (not sure if these are correct versions)
http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/date.html

Comment: [ncurses-5.2](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/SPECS/ncurses-5.2-3.spec) is rather old (but so is AIX).

Comment: CentOs users... `sudo yum install ncurses-devel`

Answer (score 0):

Installing `libncurses5-dev` and `libtinfo-dev` packages did the trick for me. I didn't even bother using the `--with-tlib` argument and configure just worked. Might be that the `libtinfo-dev` package alone would do. My system is a fresh Debian 8.3.

`

Comment: Dude, he is on an IBM AIX. It is a very different system from Debian.